# How do i add a bank account associated to stripe customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, payment

I'm building an app in ruby on rails within which the merchant provides his bank account info and his payments are supposed to be processes monthly.

I'd like to achieve this using stripe.
How do i add/create a bank account associated with a stripe customer?

Answer (score 2):

First we need to find the stripe customer and after that we can  add a new bank account in that customer account. 
You can refer this code for more details

```
# Add bank account data on stripe for patient users
def add_bank_account
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_id)
  customer.sources.create({:source => {:object => "bank_account", :account_number => bank_account_number,  :country => country,  :currency => "USD", :account_holder_name => account_holder_name, :account_holder_type => account_holder_type, :routing_number => routing_number }})
end
```

`account_holder_type` can be company or individual

In order to start the payment process you need to [verify](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#verifying) new bank account